# "$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes"

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I am sending a get request from an application and getting the below mentioned error:

```
{"$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes"}
```

I am using atlas managed mongo-db with 4GB Ram and 20 GB storage. I think, I need to update some configuration setting, but I am missing on it. Can anyone help me resolve this error.

Adding the query

```
    db.collection1.aggregate([ { '$match': {} }, { '$lookup': { from: 'collection2', localField: 'pfId', foreignField: 'pfId', as: 'pt' } }, { '$unwind': '$pt' }, { '$match': {} }, { '$lookup': { from: 'collection3', localField: 'pt.ptId', foreignField: 'ptId', as: 'pd' } }, { '$unwind': '$pd' }, { '$match': {} }, { '$lookup': { from: 'collection4', localField: 'pd.pdId', foreignField: 'pdId', as: 'dl' } }, { '$unwind': '$dl' }, { '$match': { 'dl.currentdl': { '$ne': 'OBSOLETE' }, '$or': [ { 'pd.pdName': { '$regex': /^.*world.*/i } }, { 'dl.r.dF': { '$regex': /^.*world.*/i } }, { 'dl.dlType': { '$regex': /^.*world.*/i } }, { 'dl.dlId': 'WORLD' }, { 'dl.logUserId': 'WORLD' } ] } }, { '$project': {//some_fields} }, { '$group': { _id: null, count: { '$sum': 1 }, results: { '$push': '$$ROOT' } } }, { '$project': { count: 1, results: { '$slice': [ '$results',
0, 10 ] } } }], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

I have to paginate the data, along with the retrieving the count of data fetched.

Comment: There are some [Aggregation Memory Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html#memory-restrictions).

Comment: Yeah, memory restrictions are there, for which we were able to use allowDiskUse, but now from mongo 4.0.14, it gives the above mentioned error, irrespective of allowDiskUse

Comment: You may want to post additional details about the query, the collection and the indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after so much of struggle, here is what I did to resolve my problem.
First thing was understood that I cann't push the data into an array without limiting it. So I used `$limit` and `$skip`, before grouping the data in the pipeline.(This also maintains the pagination for my query). But the problem was to maintain the total count of record as it was lost due to limit before grouping.
So, the solution i figured out is to use `$facet`, which helps me in implementing two pipelines within the same aggregation pipeline.

```
db.prdfam.aggregate([{
$facet: {
"counts":[
{ '$match': {} },
{ '$lookup': { from: 'pt', localField: 'pfId', foreignField: 'pfId', as: 'pt' } },
{ '$unwind': '$pt' }, { '$match': {} }, 
{ '$lookup': { from: 'prds', localField: 'pt.ptId', foreignField: 'ptId', as: 'prd' } },
{ '$unwind': '$prd' }, { '$match': {} }, 
{ '$lookup': { from: 'del', localField: 'prd.prdId', foreignField: 'prdId', as: 'delivery' } }, 
{ '$unwind': '$delivery' }, { '$match': { 'delivery.currentDelivery': { '$ne': 'OBSOLETE' }, 
'$or': [ { 'prd.prdName': { '$regex': /^.*world.*/i } },
{ 'delivery.rInfo.dataFormat': { '$regex': /^.*world.*/i } },
{ 'delivery.dType': { '$regex': /^.*world.*/i } }, 
{ 'delivery.dId': 'WORLD' }, { 'delivery.UserId': 'WORLD' } ] } }, 
{ '$group': { _id: null, count: { '$sum': 1 } } }
],
"results":[
//same lookup & match conditions as in above element 
{ '$project': { //fields to project } }, 
{ '$sort': { updatedAt: -1 } }, {$skip: 0},{ $limit : 10 },
{ '$group': { _id: null, results: { '$push': '$$ROOT' } } },
{ '$project': { results: 1 } }
]
}
}], 
{ allowDiskUse: true })
```

Hope this will help others. Cheers :)

Comment: i'm having the same error message even using allowDiskUse:true, do you have another solution @Ruchika Sharma?

Comment: @jguilhermeam Yes, allowDiskUse doesn't work from 4.0.14 mongo version. The best way is to optimize the query so as to reduce the output of the query. In my case, I have to break my aggregation pipeline into two parts for which i used $facet.

Comment: yes, i was pushing two named fields in $push, then i've changed to only one string. it worked. thanks

Comment: @RuchikaSharma
Can you take a look to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127323/memory-overflow-error-when-using-aggregate-and-group-queries/69128001?noredirect=1#comment122181508_69128001
I apply $facet in my case but not work. May be I am wrong some thing about syntax? –