# Memory overflow error when using aggregate and $group queries

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, bigdata, query-optimization

I have a collection named "allvoice" which has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5cbf38"),
    "subscriber_id" : "e3365edb9c781a561107242a81c1a92b4269ef9a",
    "callednumber" : "559198e6f8814773551a457e53a614d603f9deab",
    "originaltimestamp" : "20200113033803",
    "duration" : "13",
    "maincost" : "255.6",
    "type" : "Internal",
    "type_network" : "local_network",
    "month" : "202001"
}
```

with the field "originaltimestamp" being the transaction period of the data of the day, to make it easier to query for large data during the day, I use the query "aggregate" and "group" by date to get the subscriber transactions by day (dailly transaction) and then I write out to a collection named "dailyvoice". From now on to query the transaction data by date, I will query directly in the collection "dailyvoice". Here is my query.

```
db.getCollection('allvoice').aggregate(
  [ 
  { 
      "$project": {
       "date": { "$toDate": "$originaltimestamp" },
       "subscriber_id":1,
       "callednumber":1,
       "originaltimestamp":1,
       "duration": 1,
       "maincost": 1,
       "type": 1,
       "type_network": 1,
       "month":1
  }},
 
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$date" } },
    "data": { $push: "$$ROOT" } ,
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  {
    '$out': 'dailyvoice' 
  }
],  { allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

And the output of the "dailyvoice" collection is as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "2020-01-13",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5cbf38"),
            "subscriber_id" : "e3365edb9c781a561107242a81c1a92b4269ef9a",
            "callednumber" : "559198e6f8814773551a457e53a614d603f9deab",
            "originaltimestamp" : "20200113033803",
            "duration" : "13",
            "maincost" : "255.6",
            "type" : "trong nuoc",
            "type_network" : "local_network",
            "month" : "202001",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-01-13T03:38:03.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5cbf39"),
            "subscriber_id" : "6cf5d711bfa12160eefe62b8bc9c914370eebd70",
            "callednumber" : "0241052d42e5491b0529733716fb6fb04804248f",
            "originaltimestamp" : "20200113041608",
            "duration" : "28",
            "maincost" : "644.0",
            "type" : "trong nuoc",
            "type_network" : "global_network",
            "month" : "202001",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-01-13T04:16:08.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5cbf3a"),
            "subscriber_id" : "3e554a5a920c469da9faf7375c5265c5cf6fb696",
            "callednumber" : "307219a71c028931a4b74f8f5f014ffa16005ee9",
            "originaltimestamp" : "20200113051416",
            "duration" : "202",
            "maincost" : "2961.4",
            "type" : "trong nuoc",
            "type_network" : "local_network",
            "month" : "202001",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-01-13T05:14:16.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "count" : 3.0
}
```

The problem I have here is that if the collection "allvoice" has a small data set, the query statement works fine, but when the collection "allvoice" has a large data set, about 114513872 records (documents) the statement the query encountered an overflow ("PlanExcutor error during aggregation").
Is there a better solution than increasing the server configuration?
Please take a look to find a way to optimize the query for me! Thanks you so much

After I optimize the query to query month by month, the result is that I still get the error: "PlanExcutor error during aggreation::cased by::BSONObj size.."

```
db.getCollection('allvoice').aggregate(
    [

        { $match: { month: "202001" } },

        {
            "$group": {

                "_id": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": { "$toDate": "$originaltimestamp" }
                    }
                },

                "data": {
                    $push: {
                        "subscriber_id": "$subscriber_id",
                        "type": "$type",
                        // "originaltimestamp":"$originaltimestamp"
                        "date": { "$toDate": "$originaltimestamp" },
                        "month": "$month"
                    }
                },

                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        },
        
        {
            '$out': 'dailyvoice_202001'
        }
    ], { allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

You don't need the first `$project` stage in the query. And, you can include the `{ "$toDate": "$originaltimestamp" }` within the `$group` stage's `_id`, as below:

```
"_id": { 
    "$dateToString": { 
        "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": { "$toDate": "$originaltimestamp" } 
    } 
}
```

About the `$push: "$$ROOT"` - instead of the `$$ROOT`, capture only the fields you need most (or important). This is to reduce the memory usage. For example:

```
"data": { 
    $push: { 
        "subscriber_id": "$subscriber_id",
        "type": "$type",
        // other required fields...
    } 
}
```

Finally, you can think about restricting the query for a set of dates at time. This will require running the query more than once for different range of dates - but I think it may fare better overall. For example, a month at a time matching the `month` field. And, this `month` can be indexed for performance. This will require to include a `$match` stage at the beginning (the first stage) of the query, for example:

```
{ $match: { month: "202001" } }
```

And, this will query data for the month of January 2020.

Comment: Thanks you for your comments. I tried to run the query according to your suggestion and added the condition " { $match: { month: "202001" } }" to shrink the data set, but since 1 month's data is too much large (I think) so the timeout error "Failed to execute all of the script. The script has reached shell timeout (15 seconds) limit.
Please increase the value of shell timeout using button below or from the main window menu "Options->Change Shell Timeout"

Comment: If assuming the query according to your suggestion is running correctly, then my writing to the "daillyvoice" collection will also be affected, because every time I run the data for 1 month, the next time's data will be overwrite previous data and write to "dailyvoice" collection

Comment: I refer to a bug in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714842/push-used-too-much-memory-and-cannot-spill-to-disk-memory-limit-104857600-by
and i also tried using "$facet" in my query statement, but it doesn't work, any suggestion about $facet in this case? Do you think I misunderstood the use of $facet in this case?

Comment: _"... overwrite previous data and write to "dailyvoice" collection... "_: You can use the collection name like "dailyvoice_202001", for example.

Comment: Well, maybe to split by month like that, then merge into 1 collection if necessary. But the problem is that if I run the query month by month I still get the timeout error. Do you have any suggestions if using "$facet" in this problem?

Comment: What kind of shell tool are you using to run your query? You may want to refer the tool documentation regarding the _timeout_ issue and follow any instructions.

Comment: I am using robo3t, it's timeout so now I've change to git bash (shell command) but not work also. If I using git bash command line the error is following: "on connection: connection to 192.168.1.16:2701 : aggregate failed :_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:719:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:811:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:276:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1058:12

Comment: Can you correct the querry for me if using $facet? @prasad_

Comment: I am not familiar with git bash or robo3t tools usage with MongoDB. An option you can try is running the query using `mongo` shell or the newer `mongosh`. There is a [connectTimeoutMS](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/connection-string/index.html#urioption.connectTimeoutMS) you can specify in the server connection string (it is by default have no timeout).

Comment: I just switched to Studio3T, the error message is like this: 
"PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: BSONObj size: 31954416 (0x1E795F0) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: \"2020-01-01\"""

Comment: _"... BSONObj size: ..."_ : See the MongoDB documentation on [Aggregate Result Size Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#result-size-restrictions).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236963/discussion-between-cauchuyennhocuatoi-and-prasad).